# Centrar botón de búsqueda

Tags: html, html5, css, botón

Con la aplicación web ya terminada solo falta el CSS, y aquí estoy teniendo problemas.

Tengo el siguiente botón:

```html
<div class="SearchDiv">
  <form id="searchForm" action="SearchController" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="searchQuery" required /> <input
    type="submit" name="searchBtn" title="search" value="search">
  </form>
 </div>
```

La cosa es que por mucho que intente no soy capaz de hacer que el buscador se situe en el centro de la pantalla con un tamaño relativamente grande.

¿Alguna idea del css que debo aplicar?

UPDATE: El css que he estado intentando utilizar ha sido este, que en un botón similar me funciona:

```
   .SearchDiv {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 55px;
}
```

Comment: prueba con esto : margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deberías concretar más tu estructura HTML y los estilos que afectan a la misma. Para el HTML que has puesto en tu pregunta bastaría con lo siguiente:

```css
.SearchDiv{
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="SearchDiv">
    <form id="searchForm" action="SearchController" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="searchQuery" required /> <input
            type="submit" name="searchBtn" title="search" value="search">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya me funciona, muchas gracias.